# How to find a basis for the null space

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is a $3x3$ matrix of rank $2$. The system of equations

$Ax = [3\,\, 5\,\,  7]^T$

has infinitely many solutions, including $x = [1\,\,2\,\,3]^T$ and $x = [4\,\,4\,\,4]^T$. A basis for the null space of $A$ is:

A) ${(1,1,1),(2,3,5)}$

B) ${(1,2,3),(3,5,7)}$

C) ${(3,2,1)}$

D) ${(3,5,7)}$

E) ${(2,3,4)}$

I do not know how to find the null space without the matrix $A$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some relevant questions to think about: What is the dimension of the null space? Can you find a vector in the null space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the rank-nullity theorem, notice that the dimension of the null space of $A$ is $3 - 2 = 1$. Hence, it suffices to find a single nonzero vector that satisfies the corresponding homogeneous system $A \vec x = \vec 0$. Indeed, suppose that $A\vec u = A\vec v = \vec b$ for some distinct $\vec u, \vec v$. Then:
$$
A(\vec u - \vec v) = A\vec u - A\vec v = \vec b - \vec b = \vec 0
$$
where $\vec u - \vec v \neq \vec 0$, as desired.